# Mouse points on one info icon, Tooltip opens multiple times

Tags: html, angular, devexpress

if I put my mouse pointer on one of the info buttons, it will show both tooltips. How can I prevent this? I just want to show the one tooltip, on which the mouse pointer points to. Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <div class="dx-fieldset-header">Dateianhänge<span class="dx-fieldset-header-subtext"> Download / Löschen</span></div>
    <div class="dx-field">
      <div class="anhang-liste">
        <mat-chip-list *ngIf="data?.anhanglist.length" aria-label="Anhänge löschen">
          <mat-chip *ngFor="let anhang of data?.anhanglist" class="anhang-chip">
            <span class="anhang-filename" (click)="downloadAnhang(anhang)">
              {{ anhang.dateiname }}
            </span>
            <mat-icon  *ngIf="!IstAnhangBereitsInKontoauszugszeileVerwendet(anhang.id)" class="anhang-delete" (click)="deleteAnhang(anhang)">cancel</mat-icon>
            <i
            *ngIf="IstAnhangBereitsInKontoauszugszeileVerwendet(anhang.id)"
            style="margin-left: 0.2em;"
            class="fa fa-info-circle"
            id="infoKontoauszugzeilenAnhang{{anhang.id}}"
            (mouseenter)="toggleDefault()"
            (mouseleave)="toggleDefault()"
          >
          <dx-tooltip
          *ngIf="IstAnhangBereitsInKontoauszugszeileVerwendet(anhang.id)"
            target="#infoKontoauszugzeilenAnhang{{anhang.id}}"
            [(visible)]="defaultVisible"
            [closeOnOutsideClick]="false"
          >Verwendet in folgenden Kontoauszugzeilen:
            {{zeilenNummernMitAnhang[anhang.id]}}
          </dx-tooltip>
          </i>
          </mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: closeOnOutsideClick = true, did you try that?

Comment: @Aakash I tried it, still the same problem